# Cloud SQL Server get sa password

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-sql

I have created an SQL Server instance in Google Cloud SQL, I have the *sqlserver* user but it doesn't have sysadmin permission, so I want to know if it's possible to get or reset the password of the *sa* user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Cloud SQL is a managed service there are certain permissions are not given to the user. Therefor the SUPERUSER and REPLICATION privileges are not given.